# Image doesn't load via url

Tags: android, react-native

Image object doesn't loads images via url.

```
<Image style={{height: 120, width: 120}} source={{uri: 'http://somedomain.com/'+this.props.icon}}/>
```

And if I download this image via RNFS to local directory (I've checked images downloaded correctly) and try to load then it fails:

```
<Image style={{height: 120, width: 120}} source={{uri: 'res/'+this.props.icon}}/>
```

Even if i try path with RNFS constant it doesn't works too:

```
<Image style={{height: 120, width: 120}} source={{uri: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+'/res/'+this.props.icon}}/>
```

UPD 
I don't know why but remote image doesn't work only sometimes (on some domains independent of http or https)
And I have made check for every local image before render:

```
RNFS.exists(LOGOPATH+this.props.logo).then((data)=> {
  console.log(data)
})
```

And it returned true for every image, it means that path is correct

Comment: Can you try use https only?

Comment: No, i need to download file in local directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method in your java file

```
public void loadPimage(String picUrlString){

    Glide.with(this).load(picUrlString).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(YourImageView);
}
```

and call it like this

```
loadPimage(YourURL);
```

but dont forget to add `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'` to your dependencies in Build.gradle file